# Hello World! на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Помогите разобраться с проблемой в Delphi XE, возникшей с первой программой.
Код:

```
program Helloworld;          //название программы
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}           //директива компилятору о создании консольного приложения
begin
  writeln('Hello, world!');    //вывод сообщения Hello, world!
end.                         //конец программы
```

После компиляции окно с текстом появляется на мгновение и исчезает. В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить?

Comment: надо че-то типа readln; в конце программы

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет никакой проблемы. Программа запускается, выводит 'Hello, world!' и спокойно завершается, то есть делает именно то, что от нее и хотели.

---

Если хотите, чтобы программа перед закрытием повисела 3 секунды, например, исправьте на такой вариант:

```
program Helloworld; //название программы
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} //директива компилятору о создании консольного приложения
uses sysutils;

begin 
  writeln('Hello, world!'); //вывод сообщения Hello, world!
  sleep(3000);
end. //конец программы
```

Answer (score 11):

Достаточно просто написать ReadLn перед последним end - тогда программа будет ждать нажатия клавиши Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй в конце программы поставить `Readkey;`

Comment: Для работы функции ReadKey, нужен модуль Crt, его в Delphi нет, но можно его Интернете найти. Но мне попадался лишь такой Crt, в котором не работают функции ReadKey и KeyPressed.